# <form> tag causes Sharepoint error in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sharepoint

So, I am working on .aspx application on Sharepoint, and I wanted to add form dialog. (question is not about how to make dialog, I did it). Problem is that when I use:

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
     <form id="Form1" runat="server">
                <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
                </div>
     </form>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

I get error,

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.

Logs say nothing special.

but when i just remove form tags, even dialog work properly but I cannot use few things that I need. In that div I have aspx controls and to make them visible I want to put them into form.

Comment: Probably you are inadvertently nesting forms.

Answer (score 0):

sharepoint masterpages already contain a form tag.

either you remove the form tag or you stop using a master page